# BoxOrMutRef From conversions for dyn traits

Tags: rust, traits

I want to implement an enum that holds either a `Box` or a mutable reference that should be convertible from either of the two:

```
pub enum BoxOrMutRef<'a, T: ?Sized + 'a> {
    Boxed(Box<T>),
    MutRef(&'a mut T),
}

impl<'a, T: ?Sized + 'a> From<&'a mut T> for BoxOrMutRef<'a, T> {
    fn from(v: &'a mut T) -> BoxOrMutRef<'a, T> {
        BoxOrMutRef::MutRef(v)
    }
}

impl<'a, T> From<T> for BoxOrMutRef<'a, T> {
    fn from(v: T) -> BoxOrMutRef<'a, T> {
        BoxOrMutRef::Boxed(Box::new(v))
    }
}
```

When I try to use these conversion functions for `dyn` traits...

```
trait MyTrait {}

fn test1<'a>(v: impl Into<BoxOrMutRef<'a, dyn MyTrait>>) {}

struct MyStruct {}

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {}

fn main() {
    let mut v = MyStruct {};
    test1(&mut v);
    test1(v);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=46e33277335592786b91b80b0728aa86)

It fails with:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `BoxOrMutRef<'_, dyn MyTrait>: std::convert::From<&mut MyStruct>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:28:5
   |
20 | fn test1<'a>(v: impl Into<BoxOrMutRef<'a, dyn MyTrait>>) {}
   |    -----             ---------------------------------- required by this bound in `test1`
...
28 |     test1(&mut v);
   |     ^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<&mut MyStruct>` is not implemented for `BoxOrMutRef<'_, dyn MyTrait>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <BoxOrMutRef<'a, T> as std::convert::From<&'a mut T>>
             <BoxOrMutRef<'a, T> as std::convert::From<T>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<BoxOrMutRef<'_, dyn MyTrait>>` for `&mut MyStruct`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `BoxOrMutRef<'_, dyn MyTrait>: std::convert::From<MyStruct>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:29:5
   |
20 | fn test1<'a>(v: impl Into<BoxOrMutRef<'a, dyn MyTrait>>) {}
   |    -----             ---------------------------------- required by this bound in `test1`
...
29 |     test1(v);
   |     ^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<MyStruct>` is not implemented for `BoxOrMutRef<'_, dyn MyTrait>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <BoxOrMutRef<'a, T> as std::convert::From<&'a mut T>>
             <BoxOrMutRef<'a, T> as std::convert::From<T>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<BoxOrMutRef<'_, dyn MyTrait>>` for `MyStruct`
```

Using `test1(&mut v as &mut dyn MyTrait)` works, but I want to avoid explicit casts here. How do I have to change my `From` implementations to allow these conversions?

Comment: I just want to point out that `test1(v)` won't work regardless since the impl of `From<T>` for `BoxOrMutRef<'a, T>` needs `T` to be `Sized`. (and in general, `From<T>` requires `T` to be sized).

Comment: @SCappella But `MyStruct` is `Sized`, so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: You're trying to convert into `BoxOrMutRef<'a, dyn MyTrait>>`, though. So `T` would be `dyn MyTrait`, not `MyStruct`.(look at the trait bounds on `test1`).

Comment: Well, yes, but that is exactly my question - how do I have to change it to make it work? Manually, it works - `test1(BoxOrMutRef::Boxed(Box::new(v) as Box::<dyn MyTrait>));`